# mscorlib.dll TypeInitializationException & BadImageFormatException

Tags: c++, .net, dll

I am running a program, which as of now builds fine with no errors or warnings, and I am coming across two run time exceptions in mscorlib.dll.

I get a **TypeInitializationException** & **BadImageFormatException**, and the details of the messages are:

> System.TypeInitializationException occurred Message: A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'Service.Program' threw an exception.

And

> System.BadImageFormatException occurred Message: A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'ServiceFrameworkAPI, Version=1.0.0.668, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.

I've fiddled with the target processors to no success, my target for my project is x86 currently which I had thought to be the way to go after reading some other answers on stack overflow. I checked to break when the exception is hit, but when I see a notification about the run time exception, I am shown a tab with a screen that says "Source Not Available". The exception is thrown immediately before the program enters main.

It also may be worth noting that my solution includes a Managed C++ project, which I think may have something to do with that based on other SO questions. I have read around SO already but I won't be offended if you point me to any other answers, .NET is brand new to me so I may have missed something important. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are probably just changing the wrong setting, changing the solution platform instead of the platform target.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target setting.

Comment: I actually have been changing that field, and I can't resolve the issue. I also have two build warnings (which I had before posting this question, and resolved, but now they're back) which tell me there is a mismatch between processor for which project is being built and of project reference. The thing is, the warning says the the project is being built  for "x86" and the architecture of the reference is "AMD64", which I'm sure is some 64 bit architecture but have no way to specify in VS, because x64 doesn't resolve the warnings or the run time exceptions.

Comment: Clearly you are doing something very wrong but there's no hint at all in the question.  Ask a team member or friend to look over your shoulder, show him at least the Build > Configuration Manager dialog.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding teammates right now but I definitely will. They're likely to know something. I mean, right now, if I make my project's platform target x86, I get two warnings about mismatched architecture that say project is x86 but references are AMD64. If I change the project's target architecture to x64, I get 4 warnings that say project is AMD64 but references are x86. Of course these are not the same references. I did not design this project, I just inherited it to work on, is it possible to have conflicting target processors for references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity's sake if anyone ever comes across this question, I'll answer how I fixed.

It turns out I was just using references that weren't the ones I needed (although had identical names). I ended up including some projects in my solution that corresponded to the references and just referenced the projects instead of assemblies and everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

In application you are runnint - try to mark assembly: "ServiceFrameworkAPI" with option: Copy Local = True

[image]